# Determine # of molecules in an unknown sample

Tags: experimental-chemistry

How might one determine the # of molecules in an unknown sample? If the sample is a gas,  we might use $PV=nRT$ to estimate # of molecules. If the sample is a solid or liquid and the chemical formula is known, we simply need to measure the mass. But can we determine the # of molecules without first determining the chemical formula?

Answer (score 2):

There are attempts to redefine the mol through measuring spheres of monocrystalline silicon.  If you have the macroscopic dimension of your sample and the dimensions of your unit cell (from x-ray diffraction) you know how many atoms if silicon are there.

Comment: What if the substance does not exhibit crystalline structure?

Comment: Freezing-point depression

Comment: Are you telling me there is no general way to determine the number of molecules in a sample? That would be strange that something so simple requires complicated and case-specific methods to deal with.

Comment: Freezing-point depression actually works quite nicely.

Comment: That is for solutions, though. Perhaps I should ask which method experiments use, or whether they care about calculations like this at all.